# I run UNIX Network Programming Volume 1(3rd) but how to config the networking environment?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I just run the "1.2 A Simple Daytime Client" sample. but under ubuntu, how to config the networking environment?

THe sample usage is "solaris % a.out 206.168.112.96", here how should i change the IP here.  I am connect to Internet by a LAN. my ip showing by ifconfig is

`inet address: 192.168.0.109`, but here when i type `a.out 192.168.0.109`, it give a info that "connect error: Connection refused", how should i do?

Attached is this sample code:

#### intro/daytimetcpcli.c

```
  #include  "unp.h"

  int
  main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      int     sockfd, n;
      char    recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
      struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

      if (argc != 2)
          err_quit("usage: a.out <IPaddress>");

     if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
         err_sys("socket error");

     bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
     servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     servaddr.sin_port = htons(13);  /* daytime server */
     if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &servaddr.sin_addr) <= 0)
         err_quit("inet_pton error for %s", argv[1]);

     if (connect(sockfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
         err_sys("connect error");

     while ( (n = read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
         recvline[n] = 0;        /* null terminate */
         if (fputs(recvline, stdout) == EOF)
             err_sys("fputs error");
     }
     if (n < 0)
         err_sys("read error");

     exit(0);
 }
```

Anyone give any advice, i am new to networking progarmming.

I just run as one answer provided here:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/jack/dev/practice# ./daytimetcpcli 192.168.0.109
connect error: Connection refused
root@ubuntu:/home/jack/dev/practice#
```

it still give the connect error info:

I use the netstat to check info.

```
  jack@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -tlp

  activate Internet connection (just server)
  Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
  tcp        0      0 localhost:5038          *:*                     LISTEN      1625/asterisk   
  tcp        0      0 *:cisco-sccp            *:*                     LISTEN      1625/asterisk   
  tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN      1679/apache2    
  tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        *:*                     LISTEN      1405/dnsmasq    
  tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN      933/cupsd       
  tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN      1076/postgres   
  tcp        0      0 localhost:5946          *:*                     LISTEN      983/teamviewerd 
  tcp        0      0 *:sip                   *:*                     LISTEN      1625/asterisk   
  tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ipp       [::]:*                  LISTEN      933/cupsd
```

Comment: FYI, don't put line numbers in your posted code unless you really need to reference a particular line.  Even then a comment and arrow should do the trick.  The numbers make it even less likely that anyone is going to try your code.  (Not an issue on this post but for the future.)

Comment: Did you start the server before the client?

Comment: Check if you can connect to it by using `netcat`. If you get connection refused as well then either your daytime server isn't running or you have firewall blocking it.

Comment: This sample code was written at a time when running "daytime" server was standard practice on most hosts. So it expects that server to be running. But these days that is seldom done. So you may have to install linux's `netkit` or `netkit-timed` to make that work.

Comment: Rather than run your own daytime server, here is a list of public ones that you can point your client at: http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Comment: Gentlemen, he is reading Steven's network book.  The code is from the book.  It also comes with a server - actually 2 or 3 versions of a server if I remember.  OP just needs to compile one of them and successful run it so his client can connect.  It is a learning exercise in programming not a hunt for a working daytime server.

Comment: I have use the "public ones" and successfully got the time return. thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current versions of ubuntu don't have the `daytime` server installed by default, but it is easy to do.

- if `xinetd` isn't already installed, install it with `sudo apt-get install xinetd`
- edit `/etc/xinetd.d/daytime` to change `disable = yes` to `disable = no`

.

```
service daytime
{
    disable         = no
    type            = INTERNAL
    id              = daytime-stream
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    user            = root
    wait            = no
}
```

- type `sudo service xinetd reload` to make it read the changed config file
- type `netstat -a -t | grep daytime` to verify that the daytime server is running, then try running your client program again

Comment: The code OP is playing with comes with a daytime server.  He just needs to compile and run it in addition to the client.

Comment: i have install xinetd on my ubuntu, also change the config file to disable option to no.  type the latter cmd you said. but when search the daytime server, still no result. I think may the "service xinetd" step i am not right. I type the service xined. it show me "jack@ubuntu:~$ service xinetd
Usage: /etc/init.d/xinetd COMMAND
" info. how should i do? May i do not start the daytime server?

Comment: please type `service xinetd restart` in case the install of xinetd did not start it. `service xinetd` is always going to give an error, because the `service` command needs at least 2 arguments, the service name and what action to do.

Comment: thx, mark. i just use the service xinetd start but get some error info like this, seem the xinetd is run . "jack@ubuntu:~/dev/practice$ service xinetd start
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.83" (uid=1000 pid=14392 comm="start xinetd ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
jack@ubuntu:~/dev/practice$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that you need to be superuser to start or stop services. So the command is `sudo service xinetd restart`

Answer (score 7):

You should run `daytimetcpsrv` first locally, it offers as a local time server. Then you can run `daytimetcpcli 127.0.0.1` to get current time.